# How can I get data from firebase to data model?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm quite new at Kotlin. I have data class which hold image urls named testModel. I need to add data to model from firebase with that code:

Here my data model:  `class testModel(val imageLinks: List<String>)`

```
private val dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("categories").child("1").child("top")


fun readDataFromFirebase(){

    dbRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            var list = ArrayList<testModel>()
            for (e in dataSnapshot.children){
                println(e.value)
            }

        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            Log.e("DB", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
        }
    })



}
```

Actually this block can get value from firebase I can see in run console my image urls but I can't add these on my testModel. How can I make it? Also I need good tutorials for these kind of works, like data models, read and write data with Kotlin. I am waiting for your advice.

PS: I already tried `getValue` method but is give error java.lang.

Comment: Could you show the dataclass? And what exactly is the problem here? If you want to convert your snapshot to your dataclass, just class `snapshot.toObject(YourDataClass::class)` Your Dataclass should match the snapshot fields and all of them should have default values

Comment: Actually testModel is my data class. I want to hold snapshot in testModel. I will try this, but in my testModel I have List of string but I have urls in string type so is list type is wrong? Should it be only string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your dataclass, change `List<String>` with `ArrayList<String>`, because the type `List<E>` does not exist in firebase, but arrays do.

Save your data as an `Array<String>` in firebase and then when you retrieve your snapshot, do `snapshot.toObject(TestModel::class)`